# enable TLS 1.0 in windows server 2008

Tags: ssl, poodle-attack

Our production server is running on Windows Server 2008 and currently has SSL 2.0 enabled. We are looking to migrate to TLS 1.0 protocol, we did find some help online as how to disable SSL and enable TLS 1.0 in the registry. We have various LIVE applications configured in our IIS and we would like to test this migration per application basis. I assume enabling TLS in the registry would affect all the applications in the Application Pool. My question is, is there a way to disable SSL and enable TLS for a single application, test it and then propagate it to all the applications?